# TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function on Jquery-dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to use the technique's validate on Jquery-ui-Dialog but I have the error `TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function` that I find with Firebug .

I don't know because I have this error.
This is to think that I have to load a library but I loading:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

That I take on [Jqueryvalidation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

I created my case on [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/egeyat/4/edit) and to make it work exactly I want to see the alert.

Obviously after I replace with the form.
I don't know if I can not to use the latest library of Jquery.

Thank and I hope I was clear.

Comment: Excuse me, I change the link of Jsbin for see the code

Comment: You always need to load code that other code depends on first. The validate plugin depends on the jQuery library being loaded. So include jQuery first, like bipen's answer suggests

Comment: New version on http://jsbin.com/egeyat/4/edit because I loading for last the library of validate and i have the same error ian

Comment: I get no errors with your new jsbin and it works fine for me

Comment: Why no print the message that the first field is required??

Comment: Where I wrong on this question?

Comment: The poor grammar makes it difficult to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the main jquery script first.. and then the validate.js since validate requires jquery...(you are loading validate.js first and jquery.js after that)

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

.....

Comment: I don't to do the down-vote but in my project I load first the jquery and after validate and I have the same error

Comment: i mean to say jquery is included ..but if you check the jsbin... he is loading jquery after the validate.js..

Comment: @bipen Yep, that was my fault. The error the OP reported wasn't the same as what jsbin shows. As soon as I visited it, I realized this was the problem

Comment: but I have the same error http://jsbin.com/egeyat/4/edit

Comment: i don't see the `TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function` error in my console... but yes there are some other errors in it

Comment: This does not exactly solves the situation.

Comment: How did you solve the issue @bipen right now I am facing the same issue with Jquery 3.6